How to run an executable built in WSL, from Windows Explorer
I am able to build Linux GUI applications from source under WSL using GCC/Clang etc. I can also run them from the WSL command prompt (and I understand that I can have multiple command prompts open simultaneously).
Is it also possible to run such programs from Windows Explorer? I tried double-clicking and using C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe, but that didn't work.

No, it’s not; You’ll need to use WSL to run them.

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418392/how-to-elegantly-create-a-windows-shortcut-that-starts-a-wsl-program-under-x
